# Shared Memory - Array of Structs in Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, ipc, shared-memory

I want to share a list of structs between multiple processes and wrap them into another struct so i can easily keep track of my counts and size.

First I create structures and allocate my shared memory to them.

```
#define LEN 20
typedef struct msg_struct{
    int   id;
    char  topic[64];
};

typedef struct msg_list{
    int max;
    int cur_index;
    struct msg_struct* data;
};

struct msg_list* allocate_list_memory(key_t key){

    int id = shmget(key, LEN * sizeof(struct msg_struct), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    struct msg_struct* struct_list = (struct msg_struct*)shmat(id, NULL, 0);

    int id2 = shmget(key+1, sizeof(struct msg_list), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
    struct msg_list* list = (struct msg_list*)shmat(id2, NULL, 0);

    list->max = (int)LEN;
    list->data = struct_list;
    return list;
}

void add_to_memory(struct msg_list* list, struct msg_struct* msg) {

    //if we have space left just write to it
    if(list->cur_index < list->max) {
        list->data[list->cur_index].id == msg->id;
        list->data[list->cur_index].topic = msg->topic;
        list->cur_index++;
    }
    ....
}
```

Another method will than add a given msg obejct into my list of messages.

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char* result = NULL;

    struct msg_struct* msg;
    msg = (struct msg_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct msg_struct));

    msg->id = 123;
    strncpy(msg->topic, "TEST", 10);

    struct msg_list* list = allocate_list_memory(1111);

    add_to_memory(list, msg);
    ....
 }
```

My `add_to_memory` function is throwing a SIGSEGV and I really have no clue why. Other examples and tutorials don't really help me to do this correctly.

Comment: What makes you think the addreses returned by `shmat()` are going to be the same in all processes that attach to the shared memory segements?

Comment: The given example is running in one process. In another process I will call `allocate_list_memory()` again and `shmat()` will allocate the shared memory to my corresponding address space of that process. The problem I'm facing is way before I will retrieve the stored data. EDIT: i think i get what you mean...

Comment: Actually I don't get what you mean, sorry. Every process has to call `allocate_list_memory` with a given key (which is obviously the same). The list object and the array of my msg_struct will also be newly allocated with shared memory. I can't really see whats going wrong here.

Comment: `list->data` is in shared memory - shared by every process.  It's *supposed* to point to another shared memory segment.  But `shmat(id, NULL, 0);` doesn't have to return the same address in every process.

Comment: I suspect `add_to_memory()` isn't the actual code. `list->data[list->cur_index].topic = msg->topic;` doesn't compile with `msg_struct.topic` being an array.

Comment: You'll either need to pass a shared address (known by all the processes) to `shmat`, or change the pointers in the shared memory into offsets from the start of shared memory.

Comment: You need to check the return value of shmget.